# Inporting Mathematica Projects into Wolfram Workbench 2.0

Tags: ide, wolfram-mathematica, workbench

I just started to use Wolfram Workbench 2.0 (WB) for Mathematica (MMA) package development.

A friend sent me a whole project that he developed in in WB.

I put this project folder into the workspace/base area where I have other projects.
I started WB , but this friend's project is not found by WB (that is I do not see it in the Package Explorer).

I changed the preferences so that WB refreshes the workspaces at startup, restarted WB, but still the friend's project is not found in Package Explorer.

Question: how can I properly "import" this friend's project into my WB, so that i can work with it?

Comment: You may need to use File -> Switch Workspace depending on whether your project is in /Workspaces or Workspaces/Base.  Wolfram give some example projects (see [here](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/examples/)). If you import one of these can you 'see' it in  Package Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WB website](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/examples/) says about importing project examples:

- Download the zip file containing the projects by clicking the button
  below.
- Start Workbench. Once it is running, select File -> Import.... In
  the General category choose Existing Projects into Workspace and
  click Next.
- Browse to select the zip file that you downloaded, select which
  projects you wish to import, then click Finish. The projects will be 
  imported into your workspace.